# Can I prevent my windows from resizing when I drag the title bar?

Tags: windows-7

I am having trouble with moving windows for all kinds of programs.  Frequently, when I attempt to drag a window to move it somewhere else, I click too close to the top of the window, so my "drag" attempt becomes a "vertical resize".  I **never** want to resize a window by dragging on the top boundary, I am perfectly okay with using the other three sides of the window to resize.

Is there some kind of setting or program I can use to disable this behavior?

Comment: See my answer here for an understanding of how the windows border works: http://superuser.com/a/521185/127811

Answer (score 1):

You could use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to enact the window menu, then <kbd>m</kbd> to move. The cursor then snaps to a point near the top of the window for moving. It's an extra step, but might be worth it for you.

Comment: Thanks, though when I'm running into this problem it's usually because I'm trying to quickly do something else and so I miss the drag zone by a couple of pixels.  I was curious if there's something I can do to disable the resize so I don't have to worry about forgetting steps.  Maybe it's just a habitual thing, my primary os is OS X and the title bar can only be used for dragging there.