# How can I avoid accidentally re-sizing windows in Windows? (by reducing the "edge" size)

Tags: windows-7, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I prevent my windows from resizing when I drag the title bar?](https://superuser.com/questions/267037/can-i-prevent-my-windows-from-resizing-when-i-drag-the-title-bar)

In Windows 7, I find that it is very easy to accidentally resize application windows, because much of the window's title bar—which you would think you could grab to drag the window elsewhere—actually is treated as part of the window's edge. Therefore when I try to grab and drag a window, I end up resizing it.

There is [a similar question](https://superuser.com/q/267037/23135) here on SU, but that user wants to completely eliminate the ability to resize from the top edge of the window.  I want to shrink the area that is used for resizing so it's not so large.
[image: Example of how too much area is devoted to resizing]

This image illustrates the problem.  If I move my cursor a pixel or two upward it will switch modes and resize instead.  This seems ridiculous to me, since it is very near the middle of the title bar.  (I took the screen shot with an arrow rather than a resize cursor, since the resize cursor obscures any information about where the tip of the arrow *was*, and *would be* if it were still an arrow, so you'll just have to trust me that a very slight movement upward will change it.)

Comment: I explained in the body of the question how that question differs from mine.

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand,

the Move window cursor is shown whenever the mouse is over the window border.  The `BorderWidth` value is the same on all sides of the window and can be edited here in the registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics
```

BorderWidth (twips/px)
Negative values are in twips measurement and positive values are in pixels.

Default = -15/1
Maximum = -740/49

**NOTE**, by changing the `BorderWidth` value the visual size of the border will change as well!

References:

http://www.askvg.com/registry-tweak-to-decrease-window-border-size-and-padding-in-windows-8/

http://www.virtualplastic.net/html/desk_reg.html